# Remove Authentication From Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access File, which has two level protection:

1. database password
2. mdw file ( for storing username and password)

I can easily unset the ms access database password, but is there anyway to remove the username / password restriction on the ms access file?

Comment: I really do not understand the crazies who want any question about Access that doesn't explicitly involve code or SQL moved to SuperUser. This is ridiculous -- the question here is something any programmer could encounter, thus, from my point of view, it certainly belongs as a question on a programming website.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "crazies who want any question about Access that doesn't explicitly involve code or SQL moved to SuperUser" -- doing just this makes perfect sense to me. I hadn't considered it until I saw your comment. Many thanks :)

Comment: Access is a development tool, even if you can "program" in it by using point and click. I don't believe that moving questions that don't involve SQL or VBA to other sites is helpful, as the key point is that a PROGRAMMER may encounter these other problems in the course of PROGRAMMING. Why should the answers be fragmented across multiple sites, instead of kept on the site that is appropriate to the project the questioner is working on?

Comment: @David W. Fenton -- I think don't that Access should be considered an application development platform for stackoverflow purposes. I'd like stackoverflow to be reserved for true software engineers and I'd like to have MS Office 'power users', 'devs', etc to be excluded. It turns out I don't get to set the rules either but I strive to participate in the community.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: BTW keep up the good work in comments: name calling, profanity, resisting the stackoverflow community spirit, waging a one man war against the incorrect useage of word 'Access', etc. All highly entertaining and I'm *sure* will pay dividends any day soon ;)

Answer (score 1):

"How can I de-secure a database" is in the [`Microsoft Security FAQ`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165009)

Answer (score 0):

Consider migrating from .mdb format to .accdb i.e. Access2007 format a.k.a ACE. ACE no longer supports the Jet concept of user level security for new file formats.

Comment: ACE still supports it, since when working with MDBs in A2007, the ACE is doing the data manipulation. It is only the ACCDB format that doesn't support it.

Comment: @David W. Fenton gosh, you're right! I did get that wrong, didn't I? The question is, why didn't you correct it?

Comment: To give you the opportunity to correct it yourself, i.e., the same courtesy I expect from others.

Answer (score 0):

Have you lost the user/pw so that you're unable to get into the .mdb?  Or do you just want to remove the restriction?

If it's the latter then you should be able to just import all of the objects into a fresh blank .mdb.

There may be a few settings to bring over that aren't part of importable objects like forms, queries, reports, etc.  I don't remember if there's "advanced options" button on the import dialog or whether the way to import those settings is somewhere else, but it's somewhere.